# reactstrap : how to make dropDown menu's size fill all of the available space

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, reactstrap

I am using reactstrap [dropdown component](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/) as follows:

```
              <Dropdown 
                isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen[3]}
                toggle={() => {
                  this.toggle(3);
                }}
                className="mb-10" 
              >

                <DropdownToggle caret> {this.state.dropDownValue}</DropdownToggle>
                <DropdownMenu>
                  <DropdownItem >  <div onClick={this.changeValue}>operateur_sav</div></DropdownItem>
                  <DropdownItem >  <div onClick={this.changeValue}>agent_support_tel</div></DropdownItem>
                  <DropdownItem >  <div onClick={this.changeValue}>agent_magasin</div></DropdownItem>
                </DropdownMenu>
              </Dropdown>
```

which gives the following result:
[image]

This is all the form's code:

```
 <Form noValidate onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <FormGroup>
            <InputGroup>
              <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                <InputGroupText>Nom</InputGroupText>
              </InputGroupAddon>
              <Input
                type="text"
                id="nom"
                name="nom"
                value={this.state.nom}
                onChange={this.onChange}
              />
              <InputGroupAddon addonType="append">
                <InputGroupText>
                  <i className="fa fa-user"></i>
                </InputGroupText>
              </InputGroupAddon>
            </InputGroup>
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <InputGroup>
              <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                <InputGroupText>Email</InputGroupText>
              </InputGroupAddon>
              <Input
                type="email"
                id="email"
                name="email"
                value={this.state.email}
                onChange={this.onChange}
              />
              <InputGroupAddon addonType="append">
                <InputGroupText>
                  <i className="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                </InputGroupText>
              </InputGroupAddon>
            </InputGroup>
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <InputGroup>
              <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                <InputGroupText>Role</InputGroupText>
              </InputGroupAddon>
              <Dropdown
                isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen[3]}
                toggle={() => {
                  this.toggle(3);
                }}
                className="mb-10"
              >
                <DropdownToggle caret>
                  {" "}
                  {this.state.dropDownValue}
                </DropdownToggle>
                <DropdownMenu>
                  <DropdownItem>
                    {" "}
                    <div onClick={this.changeValue}>operateur_sav</div>
                  </DropdownItem>
                  <DropdownItem>
                    {" "}
                    <div onClick={this.changeValue}>agent_support_tel</div>
                  </DropdownItem>
                  <DropdownItem>
                    {" "}
                    <div onClick={this.changeValue}>agent_magasin</div>
                  </DropdownItem>
                </DropdownMenu>
              </Dropdown>
              <InputGroupAddon addonType="append">
                <InputGroupText>
                  <i className="fa fa-id-badge "></i>
                </InputGroupText>
              </InputGroupAddon>
            </InputGroup>
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <InputGroup>
              <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                <InputGroupText>Mot de passe</InputGroupText>
              </InputGroupAddon>
              <Input
                type="password"
                id="mot_de_passe"
                name="mot_de_passe"
                value={this.state.mot_de_passe}
                onChange={this.onChange}
              />
              <InputGroupAddon addonType="append">
                <InputGroupText>
                  <i className="fa fa-asterisk"></i>
                </InputGroupText>
              </InputGroupAddon>
            </InputGroup>
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup className="form-actions">
            <Button type="submit" size="sm" color="primary">
              Créer
            </Button>
          </FormGroup>
        </Form>
```

I have looked for ways to make the **dropDown menu 'role'** take-up the same size as the other **input elements** so that all the form rows's width will be the same.
My research has led me to **2 solutions**, none of which worked:
**SOLUTION 1: **

Since in reactstrap : *[The DropdownToggle uses the Button component internally, meaning it also accepts all the props the Button component accepts.](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/)*, I could use **size** and **block** like in button elements:

```
  <Button color="primary" size="lg" block>Block level button</Button>
```

which renders like this:
[image]

So I added :

```
size="lg" block
```

to the Dropdown element, but all it did is slightly enlarge the size of the dropDown menu.
**Solution 2:**
I tried to wrap the  inside a  with justified prop:

```
<ButtonGroup justified>
  <DropdownButton>...</DropdownButton>
</ButtonGroup>
```

This made absolutely no difference.
Also using:

```
 width: 100%;
```

didn't make any difference?
Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Did you try adding `width:100%` to class `dropdown-toggle`? Because when I tried the same in https://reactstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/ it worked.

Comment: @ArpithaChandrashekara yes I did and it made no difference

Comment: Can you provide Codesandbox link for the same?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-carson-y6jxm?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark @ArpithaChandrashekara I recreated the code but there's a small error I' am trying to figure out

Comment: Just modify to `export class App extends Component {`, you will be get rid of the error

Comment: @ArpithaChandrashekara What should I modify exactly?

Comment: I added default to export, it worked. But the editor is not rendering the dropDown menus properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working code for your case - https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-payne-b1rv4

There were couple of things which were wrong -

1. dropdownOpen - this should be set to boolean value but was getting assigned to some array.
2. className - this should a name and not style.

Give a className to DropdownToggle element and add `width: 100%` to that className, then your dropdown should be able to take up the entire width.

Comment: That doesn't make any difference even in your sandboxcode, if you remove className='my-dropDown' it would still be the same

Comment: Are you sure? I removed the className now, so the dropdown component shrunk back to its original size.

Comment: NOTE: I had to delete the whole formGroup and just replace it with a DropDown menu for this to work though.